# Why does Directory.GetParent() return same directory when providing trailing slash?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Directory.GetParent(@"C:\stuff");  //Returns C:\
Directory.GetParent(@"C:\stuff\"); //Returns C:\stuff
```

Why would this return two different results? What is the proper usage? The first example seems like the correct result to me.

From MSDN:

> The string returned by this method consists of all characters in the path up to, but not including, the last [`DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`AltDirectorySeparatorChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, passing the path "C:\Directory\SubDirectory\test.txt" to GetParent returns "C:\Directory\SubDirectory". Passing "C:\Directory\SubDirectory" returns "C:\Directory". However, passing "C:\Directory\SubDirectory\" returns "C:\Directory\SubDirectory", because the ending directory separator is after "SubDirectory".

It seems that it's simply naively based on the directory separator but I can't think of a good reason why it wouldn't be smarter. Is there a reasoning for implementing it like this?

Comment: since it's in the documentation, I feel like the answer is 'because that's how they wrote it'

Comment: I think it behaves this way because `C:\stuff\ ` is not a properly formatted path. The `\ ` is meant to be a directory SEPARATOR, so to have one you imply that there is a directory both to the left and right of it. To terminate a string with one, while useable, is not a properly formatted path, therefore methods and extensions referencing it cannot be blamed for providing unexpected results.

Comment: Internally it relies on `Path.GetDirectoryName`, which as you say naively [looks for the last directory separator](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,206).  I agree with @Jonesopolis - the answer is "because it does".  A _proper_ answer here would rely on the input of whoever designed it this way, any other answers are just someone's opinion on why it is so.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Although it is an answer, it's not a useful one. Some sort of reasoning of why they might have chosen to go that route is what I'm looking for

Answer (score -1):

its because with c:\stuff you are getting the parent of stuff that is c:\ and with c:\stuff\ you are getting the parent of the root of stuff wich is c:\stuff